# How can I list all worksheet tab names in another workbook in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with 40+ workbooks and need a list of every named tab in each one, for a cataloguing project. The only macros and instructions I found require creating a formula or macro for each workbook.

I have one file designated as the macro file. In it are two functions, one to sort tabs by color and one to sort them alphabetically. Both work on whatever workbook I have active, as long as the macro workbook is open in the background.

How can I list all the sheet names in the active workbook, using code  from the macro workbook?

I don't mind running the command once for each workbook, but I don't want to create a macro in every file.

Comment: Loop through workbooks by name and then loop through each sheet, copy workbook name in column A and worksheet name in column B n a new book

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Workbook.Sheets` to access the sheets of a workbook.

Likewise, you can use `Workbooks` to access the open workbooks.

You can create a nested pair of `For` loops to iterate through all workbooks, and then all worksheets.